# Able to use any case in input to generate the same dict values in output

Tags: python, dictionary, case

I have the following code:

```
people = {'Bob' : {'phone' : '12',
            'birthday' : 'May',
            'address' : 'ABC',
            'interests' : ['a', 'b', 'c']},
        'Mary' : {'phone' : '13',
            'birthday' : 'April',
            'address' : 'CBA',
            'interests' : ['d', 'e', 'f']},

            response = ['']
wrong = "I don't know. Try again or type 'quit' to get out: " 
while response[0] != 'quit': 
    response = raw_input("Please enter who you're looking for, or type 'quit' to get out: ").split() 
    try:
        print "%s's %s is %s" % (response[0], response[1], people[response[0]][response[1]])  
    except KeyError: 
        print wrong,
```

I'd like to make it so the input can be in any case and still generate the correct output. 
E.g.

```
'Mary phone', 'mary Phone', 'MARY PHONE'
```

all give

```
Mary's phone number is 13.
```

Comment: The problem with this question is Mary's phone number is 13 in the `people` dict

Comment: oops - my mistake. just made the 'output' up on the spot for this post. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Are the names all capitalized or no? `Mary` is capitalized, `bob` is not...

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer I didn't even know that existed! From now on, I will :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `capitalize()` and `lower()`

```
while response[0] != 'quit': 
    response = raw_input("Please enter who you're looking for, or type 'exit' to quit the program: ").split() 
    try:
        print "%s's %s is %s" % (response[0].capitalize(), response[1].lower(), people[response[0].capitalize()][response[1].lower()])  
    except KeyError: 
        print wrong,
```

You should change the `'bob'` key to `'Bob'`, if you go this route...

Alternatively, you can save a few more CPU cycles if you reuse results, as mentioned by rubik below.

```
while response[0] != 'quit': 
    response = raw_input("Please enter who you're looking for, or type 'exit' to quit the program: ").split() 
    try:
        fn, thing = response[0].capitalize(), response[1].lower()
        print "%s's %s is %s" % (fn, thing, people[fn][thing])  
    except KeyError: 
        print wrong,
```

Comment: Why not to assign `response[0].capitalize()` and `response[1].lower()` to some variables, since you are using it multiple times?

Comment: @rubik, that is an incremental savings in CPU cycles, but I was trying to make the answer as parallel as possible to the original.

Comment: @MikePennington: I don't think saving CPU cycles is a problem here, my advice was just for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Try making sure the input is always lowercase by converting it to lowercase with `str.lower()`. Then make sure all of your `people{}` names are lowercase as well for easy searching, and format the output back to a capitalized name when you do the output.